# Read Write Permissions on IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have create a directory `uploads` in the `Content` directory and inside the `uploads` dir i create a directory at the time of creation of user account. This setup works fine on the development setup but when i publish the site on my local `IIS` i get a access denied error.

> Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\uploads/d1bed3b7-f9e1-486a-953a-37abc7b99dad' is denied.

I have a shared hosting environment, the question i want to ask is, will i be able to set the permissions on the shared hosting environment?

What are the alternatives?

EDIT

here is code(tnx to @Marko) for creating the directory for the user

```
string UserGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Content/uploads");
Directory.CreateDirectory(path+"/" + UserGUID);
```

EDIT

after changing the code the error message has improved

> Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\uploads\ab569312-c487-4a08-bf49-99f7c69303f6' is denied.

Comment: It depends. You cannot set directory permissions by publishing; however, some shared hosting providers have a part in their administrative user interface, that you can use to set permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's a problem with the path, you have the wrong slash `/`**

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\uploads--------->/<----------d1bed3b7-f9e1-486a-953a-37abc7b99dad'
```

As long as the `\uploads\` path has writable permissions any folders/files you create within that folder **should** inherit permissions from the parent.

**EDIT**

I'm not 100% sure why it works in cassini but change your code to this (it uses `Path.Combine`) instead of adding a slash manually (which is actually the wrong slash).

```
string UserGUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Content/uploads");
string userPath = Path.Combine(path, UserGuid);
Directory.CreateDirectory(userPath);
```

**If all of this fails**, contact your hosting provider to set writable permissions to the `/uploads/` folder or use the Administration panel if you have one.

Comment: but it works fine when i use cassini... i have edited the question to add the code for creating the directory dynamically, please have a look

Comment: the wrong slash is gone after changing the code, i have updated the error message ... tnx for your time